# Invoking method via selector

Tags: objective-c, parameter-passing, selector

I am writing  a function in objective C.
That is what I got:

```
int rndValue = (((int)arc4random()/0x100000000)*width);
timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 
                                          target:self 
                           [self performSelector:@selector(doItAgain1:)  
                                      withObject:rndValue] 
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES];
```

The selector invokes this method and passes parameter:

```
-(void)doItAgain1:(int)xValuex{
}
```

At this stage the top code produces syntax error. `Syntax error: 'Expected ] before performSelector'` What is the prob?
Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be more correct:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self 
                 selector:@selector(doItAgain1:)
                 userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rndValue] repeats:YES];
```

Also notice that the syntax for the selector you call in this way must be:

```
- (void)doItAgain1:(NSTimer*)timer {

   int rndValue = [timer.userInfo intValue];
   ...
}
```

It is not possible to specify an `int` argument to such a timer selector, thus the trick to convert it into a `NSNumber` object.

Comment: Nowadays after userInfo: you can just type " @( rndValue ) "

Comment: +1 @iluvcapra, but in the end it depends on which SDK you are targeting... in any case, good to explain.

Comment: @sergio: no it doesn't. It depends on which compiler version you have.

Comment: @newacct: I don't know why in my mind each SDK version goes with an Xcode version... :-) but you are fully right, it is the compiler...

Answer (score 2):

That line should probably read

```
timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 
         target:self selector:@selector(doItAgain1:) 
         userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

You can't send a method argument with this call, in order to do that you have to do something like:

```
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
    [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(doItAgain1:)]];

[inv setSelector:@selector(doItAgain1:)];
[inv setTarget:self];
[inv setArgument:&rndValue atIndex:2];

timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval).01 
         invocation:inv 
         repeats:YES];
```